# Keep Formula In A Oracle Variable

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've a procedure that has a query as follows:

```
amtTotal number := 0;
amtTotal := round((obj.amount *  days) / obj.daysNo);
```

So what I want is to keep this thing - **round((obj.amount *  days) / obj.daysNo)** as a formula in table column and retrieve as follows:

```
AMT_NEW VARCHAR2(100);
SELECT M.FORMULA_REF INTO AMT_NEW FROM TableName m WHERE M.TYPE = '1';  

amtTotal := AMT_NEW;
```

I know, it's weird and throws the following exception:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
```

Any way I can make it work or run the formula keeping it in a variable for calculation?

Comment: amtTotal data type is number and amt_new is varchar2(100)?

Comment: What is `obj`? What is `formula_ref`? You can store an expression as a table column using [virtual columns](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1).

Comment: **FORMULA_REF** is the column name of a database table and obj is a cursor variable where the **obj.amount** is retrieved using that cursor. My plan is to keep this as a column value. Is it possible to write it like this - `SELECT M.FORMULA_REF INTO AMT_NEW FROM TableName m WHERE M.TYPE = '1'; amtTotal := AMT_NEW;  ` instead of `amtTotal := round((obj.amount *  days) / obj.daysNo);`? The second works, so I was hoping the first one should work as well or any simple way to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning the formula in the `varchar2` variable to a `number` variable.

What you really want is to evaluate the content of the `varchar2` variable and assign the result to the `number` variable. You need dynamic sql for that.

The second problem is that you have variables in the expression whose values you need to pass when running the dynamic SQL. The dynamic SQL does not know the context of your procedure and therefore cannot refer to variables in the procedure.

To evaluate a string expression and return the result as a number you can use the following function. But this does not take variables into account:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION eval_num(p_string VARCHAR2)
   RETURN NUMBER
AS
   l_result   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT (' || p_string || ') FROM dual'
      INTO l_result;

   RETURN l_result;
END;
/
```

So something like `SELECT eval_num('2*3') FROM DUAL;` returns 6, but you can *not* use `obj.amount` or `obj.daysNo` in the expression.

Actually, I would have written this as a comment, but the text is too long for that and the formatting would be worse. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what the inputs to the stored expression will be. If they are all from the same table, then you can define a virtual column:

```
create table tablename
( amount       number
, days         number
, daysno       number
, formula_ref  generated always as ((amount *  days) / daysNo) );

insert into tablename(amount, days, daysno)
values (100, 5, 2);

select * from tablename;

    AMOUNT       DAYS     DAYSNO FORMULA_REF
---------- ---------- ---------- -----------
       100          5          2         250
```

If they are from different tables, you could create a view joining them and including the formula.

If they are PL/SQL variables, you could define a function or an object type.